# product of zeta(k)

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product

The product $\prod_{k\geq 2}\zeta(k)$ converges. Is the limit a known constant ?

(This infinite product is involved in the estimation of the covolume of $SL_n(\mathbf Z)\backslash SL_n(\mathbf R)$...)

Thanks !

Comment: Mathematica returns $\approx 2.29486$; $(1-e^{-\gamma})^{-1} \approx 2.28029$. Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks ... I also arrived at this estimation using pari gp, but could not find any ressemblance with combinations of known constants. Note that the sequence $\prod_{2}^n \zeta(k)$ is strictly increasing though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be known only as $\ \prod_{k\geq 2}\zeta(k)$.

See OEIS entry [A021002](https://oeis.org/A021002) for references especially Bernd Kellner's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0604505) 'On asymptotic constants related to products of Bernoulli numbers and factorials'.

It appeared in Steven Finch's excellent 'Mathematical Constants' [page 274](http://books.google.com/books?id=DL5iVYNoEa0C&pg=PA274) (the link appeared broken at OEIS) as 'the average number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of any given order' with additional references or in connection with the 'arithmetic properties of class numbers of finite simple groups' in Henry Cohen's classical book of Computational Algebraic Number Theory.

It appeared too in Simon Plouffe [table of constants](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/gendev/) (returning these [various expansions](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/gendev/229485.html)).