# Product of Zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product

Looking at [this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303149/probability-of-generation-of-mathbb-z2), I became curious about the value of

$$
p=\prod_{j=2}^\infty \zeta(j)^{-1}
$$

In particular, is $p>0$ (assuming it converges)?

Comment: See the related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394120/product-of-zetak (and the links given there).

Comment: Yes, see the comments at the MO post:" Here is a quick heuristic that can probably be turned into a proof that it's bounded away from 0"

Comment: Here another one https://oeis.org/A068982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Euler's product ensures $\zeta(j)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1} {p^j}\right)^{-1}$ we have
$$ \log\zeta(j)=\sum_{p}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m p^{mj}}, $$
$$ \sum_{j\geq 2}\log\zeta(j) = \sum_{p}\underbrace{\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{mp^m(p^m-1)}}_{\Theta\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)} $$
and the wanted product (which is the exponential of the opposite of the LHS) is clearly convergent.
Its numerical value is approximately $0.435757$.